# log4j2 exception outputs with unexpected symbols

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using log4j2 for my project, however when an exception occurs there are symbols like `~[classes/:?]` or `~[?1.8.0_162]`. I am wondering How these syntax come and how to remove these symbols `~[?:  ]` when logging? 
Thanks.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_162]
at com.proxy.client.ProxyClientFactory.connect(ProxyClientFactory.java:23) ~[classes/:?]
```

Below is part of my log4j2.xml

```
    <Routing name="ConsoleLog">
        <Routes pattern="$${ctx:threadName}">
            <Route>
                <File name="consoleLog" fileName="${ctx:threadName}/console.log" >
                    <RegexFilter regex=".*(html|div|table).*" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT" />
                    <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_MSG_PATTERN}" />
                </File>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </Routing>
```

Answer (score 0):

The symbols at the end of the line (ie: `~[?:1.8.0_162]`) are called "[packaging data](http://macstrac.blogspot.ca/2008/09/better-stack-traces-in-java-with-log4j.html)" and you'll need to configure a log4j layout to remove them.

I'm assuming that your `LOG_MSG_PATTERN` contains something like `xEx`, `xException`, or `xThrowable` which enable this feature. Replacing that pattern item with `ex|exception|throwable` or `rEx|rException|rThrowable` should remove it.

For more information on layouts, you can see the log4j2 docs here:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html